# "I will be thankful TO you" vs. "I will be thankful FOR you"

Tags: prepositions

What preposition is correct or more accepted when telling someone that if he will bring me a reference for his things then I will be thankful?

> "I will be thankful **TO** you"

or

> "I will be thankful **FOR** you"

Answer (score 4):

In the first place, I would use *grateful* instead of *thankful* there, but the latter works too.

> I will be grateful/thankful to you.

This means you will be thanking the person for favors shown. This is probably what you want to express.

> I will be grateful/thankful for you.

This means you will direct your reverence and gratitude toward some third party or agent that brought into this world the person who is doing you the favor. It's unlikely that this is what you want to say.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to understand how in the second sentence that you wrote, the meaning is about 3rd person while in this sentence there is no mention for such person (3rd) but only 2nd person.

Comment: If you're thankful *for* something, you're just happy that it is there and doing what it's doing (or did). You're not thanking that thing (or person) itself. Bottom line: use *to* if you wish to thank the person directly.

Answer (score 2):

You are thankful to somebody, but you are thankful for something.

So the second sentence is not grammatical.

You can also use the more common grateful instead of thankful as follows:

I'll be grateful (to you) if you bring.........

To be more polite, you can say:

"I would be grateful (to you) if you could bring........."

Furthermore, the use of the verb appreciate is more common than that of the adjective grateful:

I would appreciate it if you could bring.........

Comment: The second sentence is *not* ungrammatical. It's perfectly grammatical. It just doesn't mean what the OP wants to say.